# Receive notification when user cancels MS Store subscription?

Tags: windows, azure, uwp, windows-store-apps, wns

I'm currently research if there any way to *get notify our server* when subscription status had change (expired or cancelled manually). I had read two related articles:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/change-the-billing-state-of-a-subscription-for-a-user
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/enable-subscription-add-ons-for-your-app

For now the only way I see, is to check status on purchase validation via Azure, which happens on login in my case (which is not notification obviously), disadvantages of this approach that there would be a ton of notification from each user who logon, even if there no any changes in subscription.

Another possible options (I guess) is to send notification using WNS or Azure, according to articles:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/windows-push-notification-services--wns--overview
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-wns-push-notification

I see it's possible to send direct notifications to cloud service, but I can't find any information on how to subscribe to user subscription changes, is it even possible?

Comment: It may be impossible to subscribe to user subscription changes now.

Comment: @DasiyTianMSFT additionally I've contacted MS support, seems you are right, there no any way to receive notify on user subscription status. Though google play and appstore has it, don't you know if there any plans to add this functionality to MS store?

Comment: You could give your feature request in [Feedback](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/) so that MSFT might will add it to their to-do-list based on your idea.